# HttpURLConnection in Android SDK 23 to ASP page, giving a cookie correctly to re-use session

Tags: android, asp.net, session, cookies

I have an Android app that communicates with an internal web server here.
So far I have a login activity and another activity that helps do repetitive work.

I can login fine and I can store the Session ID cookie into a string. I've verified that the string is passed correctly through intent to the next activity. I have also verified that the cookie is received in the next activity.

However when I try to give this cookie to the web server via a setRequestProperty, the server doesn't seem to use it. When my app reads the requested URL, it just gets a login page, meaning it was redirected and the cookie didn't work. I receive zero errors.

I've talked to the website creator, and he says that he does no custom handling of HTTP headers, and that all of his scripts utilize session variables, and that ASP manages the session on its own. He wasn't aware that the web site was setting a session ID and value via cookies, and we then figured out that ASP was doing it automatically. This site has been functional via a web browser for years, I'm just trying to port a specific feature from it to an app.

I don't know what I'm doing wrong. Here is the chunk of code that reads the URL and sets the cookie and other HTTP header fields:

```
private class GetURLContent extends AsyncTask<URL, Integer, String> {
    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        setData(result);
    }
    protected String doInBackground(URL... url) {

        String pageText = "";
        String charset = "UTF-8";
        String SessionCookie = "No SessionCookie passed.";
        Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
        if (extras != null) {
            SessionCookie = extras.getString("SessionCookie");
        }
        try {

            URL ThisURL = new URL(url[0].toString());
            HttpURLConnection ThisConnection = (HttpURLConnection) ThisURL.openConnection();
            ThisConnection.setRequestMethod("GET");
            ThisConnection.setRequestProperty("Host","technology.fergflor.k12.mo.us");
            ThisConnection.setRequestProperty("User-Agent", "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/41.0.2228.0 Safari/537.36");
            ThisConnection.setRequestProperty("Connection","keep-alive");
            ThisConnection.setRequestProperty("Cookie",SessionCookie);
            ThisConnection.connect();

            // wrap the urlconnection in a bufferedreader
            BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(ThisConnection.getInputStream()));
            String line;

            //read from the urlconnection via the bufferedreader
            while ((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null)
            {
                pageText = pageText + line + "\n";
            }
            bufferedReader.close();
            pageText = SessionCookie + "\n" + pageText;

        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            pageText = "MalformedURLException Error Message=\"" + e.getMessage() + "\" " + pageText;
        } catch (IOException e2) {
            pageText = "IOException Error Message=\"" + e2.getMessage() + "\" " + pageText;
        } catch (NullPointerException e3) {
            pageText = "NullPointerException Error Message=\"" + e3.getMessage() + "\" " + pageText;
        }
        return pageText;
    }
}
```

All of the set-request properties here are identical to the ones used in the previous activities login class. I am using HttpURLConnection in both activities.

The goal is to use this class to give a cookie to re-use the session established from the previous login activity, and to retrieve a web page. I'm not sure what's going wrong.

Answer (score 0):

I had a very similar problem with code that worked fine with API < 23. With API 23 it was redirected to the login page. The solution was to add this code line:

```
ThisConnection.setInstanceFollowRedirects(false);
```